# Responding to GDPR Article 15 requests if all data is already accessible via website

Tags: gdpr, website

So, Article 15 of the GDPR gives the user the right to access all the personal data concerning him or her.

Assume we have a website with user accounts. We store some information that is regarded as personal data. However, the user can easily access all of this data via browsing the website while logged into their account.

Can we respond to article 15 requests by referring them to log in to the website and browse around? Or do we explicitly need to gather all their personal data into a single file and give them this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can respond with instructions to access the data via the web site, assuming it really is comprehensive.

Comment: Thanks. This simplifies our scenario, since nearly all data is already accessible by the user. This means we just have to add some views for the remaining data.